# Selecting subdocument in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb

Given the following document:

```
{"classes":3,
"people" : [

    {name:John,
    age:20,
    city:London}

    {name:Alice,
    age:56,
    city:Dublin}

]
}
```

I have many documents like this in my database. I want to only select the **first** subdocument in the array (here John), and then sort all my documents with respect to the age of the person in the first subdocument.
I also want to only select the overall documents where number of classes is bigger than zero.
I want to create a sorted tuple with the age of the first person in each document, this was my idea to start:

```
sorted([(m['age'], m) for m in people.find({"classes":{'$gt':0}},{'people.1':1}  )])
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: About sorted tuple. What should be in there besides age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sort with pymongo driver (you can also control the direction of the sorting with `DESCENDING` and `ASCENDING` arguments of the `sort` method of the pymongo):

```
from pymongo import DESCENDING
people = db.people.find({"classes": {'$gt': 0}}).sort('people.0.age', DESCENDING)
```

and then create a list of tuples with python.

```
[(p['people'][0]['age'], p) for p in people]
```

Hope i understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry I didn't answer your comment earlier, but this is exactly what I needed. cheers x

Answer (score 1):

You should do the selecting and sorting in Mongo rather than in Python for performance reasons.  I can't tell if you want the entire subdocument in the tuple or just the age, but here is how you would do it.

Sample data:

```
> db.tuple.find({},{_id:0})
{ "classes" : 3, "people" : [   {   "name" : "John",    "age" : 20,     "city" : "London" },    {   "name" : "Alice",   "age" : 56,     "city" : "Dublin" } ] }
{ "classes" : 3, "people" : [   {   "name" : "John",    "age" : 50,     "city" : "London" },    {   "name" : "Alice",   "age" : 56,     "city" : "Dublin" } ] }
{ "classes" : 3, "people" : [   {   "name" : "John",    "age" : 10,     "city" : "London" },    {   "name" : "Alice",   "age" : 56,     "city" : "Dublin" } ] }
{ "classes" : 0, "people" : [   {   "name" : "John",    "age" : 10,     "city" : "London" },    {   "name" : "Alice",   "age" : 56,     "city" : "Dublin" } ] }
{ "people" : [  {   "name" : "John",    "age" : 15,     "city" : "London" },    {   "name" : "Alice",   "age" : 56,     "city" : "Dublin" } ] }
```

Return just the first array document sorted by age for class > 0:

```
> db.tuple.find({classes:{$gt:0}}, {_id:0,"people":1,"people":{$slice:1}}).sort({"people.age":1})
{ "classes" : 3, "people" : [ { "name" : "John", "age" : 10, "city" : "London" } ] }
{ "classes" : 3, "people" : [ { "name" : "John", "age" : 20, "city" : "London" } ] }
{ "classes" : 3, "people" : [ { "name" : "John", "age" : 50, "city" : "London" } ] }
```

Same thing to return *just* the age:

```
> db.tuple.find({classes:{$gt:0}}, {_id:0,"people.age":1,"people":{$slice:1}}).sort({"people.age":1})
{ "people" : [ { "age" : 10 } ] }
{ "people" : [ { "age" : 20 } ] }
{ "people" : [ { "age" : 50 } ] }
```