# Subdocument selection

Tags: python, mongodb, tuples

```
{"classes":3,
"people" : [

    {name:John,
    age:20,
    city:London}

    {name:Alice,
    age:56,
    city:Dublin}

           ]
}
```

I have many documents like this in my database. I want to only select the **first** subdocuments in the array (here John), and then create an ordered tuple with only the age of the first subdocuments. (also I only want total documents where the number of classes is bigger than 0)

I am trying to do it like this :

```
list = db.people.find({"classes": {'$gt': 0}})
records = sorted([(p["people"][0]["age"], p) for p in list])
```

However this code returns

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: didn't you just ask this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564865/selecting-subdocument-in-mongo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what is happening here is that some of the documents returned by your query have an empty "people" array, so when you attempt to access `p[people][0]` you get the error about the list index being out of range, since there is no element at index 0.

If you expect that all elements in your collection should always have a non-empty people array, then you should find out why such objects exist. Another option would be to update your query to be more selective, and to not return objects

```
db.people.find({"classes": {'$gt': 0}, 'people.0' : { '$exists' : True}})
```

There may be a more appropriate query depending on how you have modeled your data that would allow you to exclude objects with an empty people array. You should also consider what would happen if you have objects that are missing the people array entirely.